# Is there a way to solve the MSVCR100.dll error and Fail to load JVM dll error on Android Studio for Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is to caution you that this is my first time Programming in Android Studio.

I have installed Java SDK V8 (even tried V14 with the same result) before installing Android Studio 3.6.2 
I input the Java_Home Variable in the environment variables
Running on Windows 10 x64 Bit

I have downloaded the IDE twice tried deleting and reinstalling the IDE and Java but I keep getting the same error. The two pictures are attached in sequence of when the errors occur. I didn't even see the android application. It occurs as soon as I open the app.

Please help me.

[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvCGM.jpg)

[Second Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKxk4.png)

Environment Variables [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSp02.png)

Environment Variables][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIKlg.png)

Environment Variables][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkID9.png)

Comment: Exactly what did you download for Java? Because it ***looks*** like you chose a 32-bit installation. That is not ideal on 64-bit Windows. You also **must** use Java 8 with Android Studio (it does not support anything newer). What value did you give JAVA_HOME (and how)? Finally, adding kotlin and mobile tags was not appropriate. Your problem is entirely with Android Studio and Java.

Comment: JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241   and the file name of the JDK executable I downloaded is jdk-8u241-windows-x64 which is meant for 64 bit machines. I double checked this point but still can't figure out whats going on. Never struggled this much before.

Comment: Why did you put a space before the JAVA_HOME folder (after the `=`)? Also, make sure you add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH`. Adversity builds character.

Comment: Thanks a lot Elliot for your quick response. I have added the screenshots of my Environment Variables in my edit. Could you take a look and let me know your thoughts? Adversity does build character but I need to start my project and I am still at installing the Android Studio IDE haha. I am sure this will be a story to tell my kids someday :)

Comment: Screenshot 5. That says JRE. Not JDK. Also, screenshots suck. Stop adding screenshots. And environment variables are evaluated from left to right (or top down), so you want the correct entry near the top (**not** at the bottom). But seriously, [no more screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/2970947).

Comment: I changed it to JDK as well. Just doesnt work. Sorry about the screenshots. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Reboot! You're on windows.

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: You might want to **edit** your question. Perhaps someone will figure it out for you. Otherwise, try patience. It's been an hour since you asked.